# TestCafe : Tests execution hangs when user moves to another window or application while tests are running in TestCafe

Tags: testing, automated-tests, ui-automation, e2e-testing, testcafe

While Test execution is going on, if I open another window or application (for multitasking) then execution just hangs on.

Can someone please tell me how can I continue execution in the background ?

```
Testcafe Version : 1.9.4
Browser - Chrome
Version - 87.0.4280.88
```

Comment: I had the same issue when running it on a remote computer and the run would pause when the remote session was closed. I downgraded to Chrome 86 and it appears to be working ok now

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the [documentation](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/getting-started/#running-the-test), inactive tabs switch to a lower resource consumption mode where tests are not guaranteed to execute correctly.

You can run the tests in [headless](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/concepts/browsers.html#test-in-headless-mode) Chrome or Firefox to work around this issue.